# KDE plasma right mouse click dead end problem

Tags: kde

I'm a new-bee to the KDE plasma interface...

So when I for some reason manged to loose the menu panel, I found this solution to get access to my programs:

```
To activate this quick minimal app menu, I right clicked my desktop and choose “Configure Desktop and Wallpaper“.
In the sidebar of the window that loads, I selected “Mouse Actions“.
Next, in the dropdown menu next to the Middle Button option, I changed that to “Application Launcher” and now I have a slick minimal desktop menu.
```

But now that I succeeded in restoring the menu panel, I would like to revert to the original right clicking menu on the desktop.

But how? Since I made the change entering the now lost menu and I can not find it elsewhere in the system settings, I find my self in a dead end.....

Thanks in advance for advice

Comment: Providing your OS & particularly release details give us the best clues as to what *software stack* you're using, thus allowing more detailed responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left-click somewhere on your desktop and keep the left mousebutton pressed for about a second to enter edit mode. You'll see a small panel at the top edge of the screen, from there choose `Configure Desktop and Wallpaper`.

Alternatively, right-click on your panel and choose `Edit Panel` from the context menu to enter edit mode.

Comment: Thanks @mook765

It did the trick....

Comment: Sorry mook765 but i don't see accepted answer by clicking the check-mark left to the answer?

Comment: Thanks mook765 and done!

Not the most user frindly interface if you ask me...